# Какую библиотеку или что использует Edwin для граф. интерфейса

Tags: scheme

Поставил себе MIT/GNU-Scheme(реализацию языка Scheme) и с ним шел редактор Edwin. Интересно что он использует, ведь написан на Scheme.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ncurses? Это предположение, лень смотреть. Графического интерфейса тут не видно, это эмулятор терминала + консольный интерфейс

Comment: Похож на Имакс. А почему вы считаете что если Схема, то у нее не может быть графики. Там FFI вполне развит, можно хоть ОупенДжиЭл пробросить.

Comment: > А почему вы считаете что если Схема, то у нее не может быть графики. Там FFI вполне развит, можно хоть ОупенДжиЭл пробросить.
Нечего подобного я не думал, просто интересно какая библиотека была использована.

Comment: да [gnu/emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) это, однозначно. запущенный в эмуляторе терминала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сказал bukkojot(спасибо ему) это эмулятор терминала + консольный интерфейс.